# Glassfish and Tomcat deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

I'm working on a Java EE application, and I'm deploying it in glassfish server, I know that this server do not require any jar files in the lib folder.
My question is if I take the EAR archive of that application, it will work on a apache Tomcat server ??
I mean is the EAR file generated contains libraries required for the app to work on any server or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat isn't a full-stack Java EE server like Glassfish is. It only runs war files, and doesn't support EJB, JMS, JTA etc. So no, an EAR developed for Glassfish won't deploy on Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And the WAR file will require to add libraries to myproject ??

Comment: No. It's not simply a matter of libraries. It's a matter of services made available by the application server. Tomcat doesn't implement all these services and they're thus not available to your application, whatever the libraries you add to it.